# XCTest output to a file

Tags: xctest

I am able to run XCTests using `xcodebuild test` command. But when I run this command it outputs the build log and then there is log from test at the end. Is there a way where I can redirect only the output of test (no build logs) to a separate file?

I couldn't find anything in xcodebuild command.

Regards
Dev

Answer (score 11):

You can use ocunit2junit https://github.com/ciryon/OCUnit2JUnit to parse the build log output into junit xml for use with Jenkins. This works with XCTest as well.

```
xcodebuild test -scheme "MyScheme" -destination "platform=iOS,id=UDID_OF_DEVICE" -derivedDataPath "$(pwd)" 2>&1 | tee out.txt
cat out.txt | tools/ocunit2junit
```

This outputs junit xml to test-reports by default. If you don't want junit xml then you can still use ocunit2junit as a reference for parsing the build output.

Comment: I have tried with xcode6.3 but not working. Can you please guide me?

Comment: It looks like the [OCUnit2JUnit](https://github.com/ciryon/OCUnit2JUnit) hasn't been updated since 2014. Facebook's [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) states that it has junit xml reporters. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 5):

xcpretty has a -r option that outputs the test results into a format of your choice: https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty